# How to create a rectangle with a high side and a lower one in css

Tags: css, shapes

i'm struggling with CSS trying to create special shape.

This is the shape i wanna create

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezoon.png)

Do you have any solution ?

Thank's

Comment: You can draw that with an HTML5 canvas.

Comment: Alternatively, `clip-path`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  transform: skewY(-6deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
  border-radius: 25px;
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```